# C++ custom string trim implementation valgrind warning

Tags: c++, string, valgrind, trim

recently I implemented a custom function for trimming std::strings that removes whitespace character prefixes and suffixes.

I tested the functionality and it works according to my unit tests, but when run the tests using valgrind, I get the following output:

```
==4486== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4486==    at 0x415DDA: is_ws_char(char) (parse.cpp:22)
==4486==    by 0x415BC6: parse::trim(std::string&) (parse.cpp:34)
```

My input test string was

```
string s("  a");
```

I do not see what is the problem here.
The code looks like this:

```
inline bool is_ws_char(const char c) {    // this is line 22 in my code
  return (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == '\r');
}


void parse::trim(std::string& str) {
  size_t len = str.size();
  size_t i = 0;
  for (; i < len; ++i)
    if (!is_ws_char(str[i]))
      break;
  const size_t start = i;
  for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    if (!is_ws_char(str[i]))              // this is line 34 in my code
      break;
  const size_t end = i;
  str = str.substr(start, end - start + 1);
}
```

Does anybody has an idea what is the problem here?
I briefly thought that is's just a valgrind oddity, but that seems to be rather unlikely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like it will fail if the string only contains spaces.

Comment: No, actually it works. I wrote a unit test containing a couple of corner cases like this.

Comment: Really? I might be wrong but it seems to me like if you call with a string containing just 2 spaces, you end up with start=2. end=0 and then calling str.substr(0,-1) which I don't think is going to work. But I might have missed something.

Comment: Well, you're right. But it works, even in the case you suggested.
I have absolutely no idea why. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is invalid

```
for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

The condition will be always equal to true because expression --i will be always >= 0 due to the fact that i is unsigned integer.

Also when str.size() is equal to zero then len - 1 will be equal to std::string::npos.